# Loop through multiple accounts in codeception functional test

Tags: php, functional-testing, codeception

I got multiple accounts: "userWithCertainRole", "userWithAnotherRole" & "userWithTwoRoles". I want to functional test a specific page for all these accounts with certain roles. The functional test is the same for all the accounts, so I don't want to duplicate the code or make multiple php files. Is there any way to loop through those three accounts in one functional test?

```
/**
 * @var string|null
 */
protected ?string $account = 'userWithCertainRole';

/**
 * @param FunctionalTester $I
 */
public function page(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $this->login($I);
    $I->amOnPage('/page');
    $I->dontSee('You cannot access this page with this role');
    $I->see('Page header');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data provider as in PHPUnit, or Codeception specific Example anotation/attribute for providing data to test method.

See https://codeception.com/docs/AdvancedUsage#Examples-Attribute

```php
/**
 * @dataProvider getRoles
 */
public function page(FunctionalTester $I, Example $example)
{
    $this->login($example['username'], $example['password']);
}

protected function getRoles(): array
{
  // keys make test output easier to understand
  return [
    'userWithRole1' => ['username' => 'username1', 'password' => 'password1'],
    'userWithRole2' => ['username' => 'username2', 'password' => 'password2'],
    'userWithRole3' => ['username' => 'username3', 'password' => 'password3'],
  ];
}
```